# Cannot log in to Azure Databricks account console

Tags: azure, active-directory, databricks, azure-databricks, microsoft-entra-id

I am trying to log in to the Azure Databricks account console for the first time.

Although I am logged in into Microsoft Entra ID (formerly Active Directory) as global administrator this does not work. I receive the following error message:

> The AAD tenant: XXX-123-abc... does not belong to any Databricks account.

I am not sure what the problem is. About a year ago I transferred the Databricks resource from another Azure account to the current one. I suspect the problem might have to do with that.

I also tried to launch the account console from the Databricks admin menu. Unfortunately, this did not work either.

Comment: You must be an Azure Databricks account admin to login into databricks console.The first Azure Databricks account admin must be an Azure Active Directory Global Administrator at the time that they first log in to the Azure Databricks account console.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have admin privileges in the Databricks workspace and I am the global administrator in Microsoft Entra ID. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/databricks-assistant-faq#q-how-do-i-enable-databricks-assistant) the first Databricks user who logs in into the account console becomes Azure Databricks account admin. The problem is, that this initial login does not work.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1373629/databricks-error

Answer (score 0):

There was an error logging in. Your user does not belong to a Databricks account.

You don't have workspace admin permission to log in to the account console. That may be the reason to get the error while logging into account console. You need to reach out to your Global Administrator to add yourself as a workspace admin using the procedure below:

Go to Admin settings, select Identity and access, click on `Add user`, enter the email of the user, and click on `ok` as shown below:

[image]

After adding the user, go to `Entitlements`, and toggle on `Admin access` as shown below:

[image]

Then you will be able to log in to the account console. For more information, you can refer to the [MS Question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1373629/databricks-error).