# Can't access azure databricks account console

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

I'm trying to access https://accounts.azuredatabricks.net/ but I'm getting the following error: [The AAD tenant XXX does not belong to any Databricks account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhzQr.png)

I was the one that created this resource and I need to access the admin console to give permission to other users.

I tried clicking on Manage Accounts, open the link directly. I checked my permissions (I'm as Contributor on this resource).
When I go to Identity and access my account is checked as admin too.
I expect to be able to open the console management to add other users.

I looked into other questions/forums too, this one has the same error but I already checked it.
[Cannot log in to Azure Databricks account console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77543071/cannot-log-in-to-azure-databricks-account-console)

Answer (score 0):

Your Databricks account admin should be the global administrator to log in to the Databricks account console for the first time. Once logged in for the first time, the user will become the Databricks account admin, and the global administrator role will no longer be required. To assign the global administrator role, follow the procedure below:

Go to Microsoft Enterprise ID (Azure Active Directory), select Roles and Administrators from the left menu, and search for the global administrator role, as shown below:

[image]

Add the user to the role. Only global administrators can assign other administrator roles.

For more information, you can refer to this [MS question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1373629/databricks-error).